# How to call object from a movie clip

Tags: actionscript, frame, movieclip, flash-cs6

How to call an object from a movie clip and display it to the next frame of the scene. With the same value of it like a health bar.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous frame, you create your container (C) and add it to the display list. You also create an instance of your object 'o1', but this one is not yet added to the display list. On the other hand, this object needs to be a class to be called by the code, from the library. An instance of a class can't be called from a movieClip. (select it > Convert to symbol > Export for actionScript > Class:`MyObject`)

```
const C:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(C);

o1:MyObject = new MyObject();
```

Next frame, you add this object to the display list in it's container:

```
this.C.addChild(o1);
```